# Spring, JPA - bidirectional @OneToMany: replace child list with another

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot

I read *a lot* of topics on this and made hundreds of experiments, but no success so far. I have following classes:

```
class Parent {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL/*, orphanRemoval=true*/)
    private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();

class Child {
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    Parent parent;
}
```

What I do is try to replace `children` list with the one provided in PATCH request:

```
    Hibernate.initialize(fromDb.getChildren());
    entityManager.detach(fromDb); // detach from JPA. I need this

    List<Child> newChildren = fromClient.getChildren();

    fromDb.getChildren().clear(); // get rid of all old elements

    for (Child child : newChildren) { // add the new ones
        child.setParent(fromDb);
        fromDb.getChildren().add(child);
    }

    ParentRepository.save(merged);
```

Behavior is following:

- when I run it as it is, it adds the new ones, but leaves the old
  ones! So I have growing number of unwanted children (sorry..)
- when I
  uncomment `orphanRemoval=true` part... **the parent is removed**!

Can you explain why it behaves this way and what can I do here?

Comment: Because that is what you configured it to do... You removed `orphanRemoval=true`. The problem is also you are cascading everything in a loop. Remove the cascade from the parent field in the child object.

Comment: thanks, looks like I've found same issue on my own in the same time :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution found.

I should have orphanRemoval=true:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
```

Now it deleted the parent because of the other cascade in @ManyToOne. I changed it to following:

`@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})`

Now it works.